# A box contains 150 oranges.If one orange is taken.....

Tags: probability

A box contains 150 oranges.If one orange is taken out from the box at random and the probability of its being rotten is 0.06, then find the number of good oranges in the box.

Comment: Number of bad ones: $150\cdot 0.06=9$?

Comment: Strictly speaking, we *don't know* the number of good oranges. There could be 150 bad oranges in the box. We can only give the estimated number of good oranges.

Comment: @akkkk: We are told that if we take an orange at random from **this** box, the probability of bad is $0.06$. It follows that there are for sure exactly $9$ bad.

Comment: @MårtenW 0.06 is the probability of a rotten one. The question asks for the number of good ones, thus $150 \times (1 - 0.06) = 141$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I read it as a "factory of boxes" question, in which some process generates uniformly distributed rotten oranges. If you know the probability for this exact box, then apparently you have already counted the rotten ones.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, I merely provided a hint rather than a full answer. The number of rotten ones is indeed nine.

Answer (score 2):

The probability that the orange is not rotten (good) is $1 - 0.06 = 0.94$. Hence, we know that $0.94$ times the total number of oranges ($150$) is the number of good oranges, which numerically is $150 \times 0.94 =141$.

Comment: But answer at the back of the book is 91.

Comment: Are you sure. If yes then Thanks.

Comment: @nye The answer can be $91$ if and only if _good_ does not mean _not bad_ in your question.

Comment: The math in @Novice's answer is sound, and I'm sure that's the solution that the text book author had in mind. But strictly speaking it is not accurate to assert that there are 9 bad oranges in the box, *because the question specifically states that one orange was removed from the box.* Therefore, there are only 149 oranges left in the box. So there *were* 9 bad apples at the start of the problem, but the question remains: was the apple that was removed bad or not? (If it *was* bad, there are indeed still 141 good oranges in the box; if it was good, then, since it has now been removed, there a

Comment: It are oranges *g*

Comment: @kmote You are very correct; I want to blame it on the ambiguity of the question posted.

Comment: @kmote: Instead of a 94% chance of 140 and a 6% chance of 141 good oranges, you might just say that the expected value is $0.94\cdot149$. But presumably the author wanted to remove the orange only hypothetically: *Find the number of bad oranges in the box given the following fact: If one removes ...*